# Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I try to use jQuery UI first time. Here I show my code:

(in wordpress index file )

```
public function enqueue_admin_scripts() 
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-1.9.1.js', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/admin.js', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js', __FILE__ ) );

    }
```

here is my admin.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#add_new_gallery").click(function(){

        // alert (456);

    jQuery(function() {
      var name = jQuery( "#name" ),
      email = jQuery( "#email" ),
      password = jQuery( "#password" ),
      allFields = jQuery( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = jQuery( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+jQuery/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
          // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\jQuery%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\jQuery%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?jQuery/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+jQuery/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

          if ( bValid ) {
            jQuery( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" );
            jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    jQuery( "#create-user" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
    });

})
```

But I am getting such error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog' .

What can be the problem? How to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the reordering of the includes and the obvious answer that jquery is already included in wordpress admin I see 2 more issues.

- 1 - "`$this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles'`" on all the 3 files tell wordpress to actually include only one file, you need to define unique handle names to not overwite the previous ones.
- 2 - You also might want to consider to define the dependencies like: `wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-1.9.1.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );` where jquery is whatever unique handle you give to your jquery file.

In conclusion you should have:

```
public function enqueue_admin_scripts() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles-new-jquery', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-1.9.1.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles-new-jquery-ui', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js', __FILE__ ), array( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles-new-jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles-my-admin-javascript', plugins_url( 'js/admin.js', __FILE__ ), array( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles-new-jquery' ) );
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes.. you are right... but in any case it does not work... no error when I click on button, and I can alert anything, but dialog does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder the plugins since admin.js is dependant on jquery UI:

```
public function enqueue_admin_scripts() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-1.9.1.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/admin.js', __FILE__ ) );
}
```

Comment: OK.. I followed your advices, now my scripts have the  order u said.    

But now admin.js does not work at all. When I write admin.js first and alert something, it does, if I change its place, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery is already loaded. And wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-1.9.1.js', **FILE** ) ); is conflicting with the jQuery object. Please check  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder your javascript includes:

```
public function enqueue_admin_scripts() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-1.9.1.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug .'-admin-styles', plugins_url( 'js/admin.js', __FILE__ ) );
}
```

You will need to make sure you have a build of jQuery UI which includes the dialog:
http://jqueryui.com/download/

If you downloaded the full library it will be included.